# =COUNTIF(A2:A17="*a*" OR "*b*") AND (B2:B17 ="*x*" OR "*y*")

Tags: excel, countif

Im trying to grab numbers for a spreadsheet that is tracking some tickets we cut to others in the company.

I need to get a count of the ones where the value in Column A is "Assigned" OR "Pending" +AND+ the value in Column B is "Not Touched" OR "In Progress"

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRPnP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A2:A17,{"*Assigned*","*Pending*"},B2:B17,{"*Not Touched*";"*In Progress*"}))
```